# Applying Stripe Discount

Tags: stripe-payments

Does anyone know if there is another way to implement discount in stripe subscription without using coupon stripe features.

I have a feature in my application that admin users can give different discount amount to a subscribe user every month.

Is there a way I can edit the "Upcoming Invoice" amount of the customer through stripe api.

Comment: What does stripe support say about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can never directly edit the total amount of an invoice -- it is automatically calculated from the sum of the values of each line item, taxes, coupons, etc.

If you don't want to use coupons for whatever reason, another thing you can do to reduce the amount of an invoice is to [create invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) with a negative value.

Comment: Hi Ywain. Thanks for the answer. You mean like this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/invoices#adding-invoice-items)